# Showing that a function has a fixed point in a given interval

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I want to be able to show that the function $g(x) = 2^{-x}$ has a unique fixed point contained within the interval $[1/3,1]$, and that the fixed-point iteration $$x_{n+1} = g(x_n), \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

converges to this unique fixed point for all starting points $x_0 \in [1/3, 1]$.

How can one go about demonstrating something like this? Any help/ guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay, I understand that this function will converge to a fixed point if I iterate over the function from a starting point contained within the interval, right? I.e. $2/3$. However, to prove that a unique fixed point is contained in the interval, what would I do?

Comment: If you apply the theorem to the complete metric space $[\frac  1 3, 1]$ then your fixed point is in this interval. All you need is the fact that $g$ maps this interval into itself and  satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How could I structure this answer mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on Banach-Caccioppoli fixed-point theorem, the following result can be proven:

**Theroem**: Let $f$ be a function which is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, and such that $f(x) \in [a,b]$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$. Then $f$ has at least one fixed-point $\alpha \in [a,b]$.

If $f \in C^{1}(a,b)$ and there exist a constant $\beta <1$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq \beta <1 \forall x \in (a,b)$ then we can conclude that there is a single fixed-point in $[a,b]$. In this case, for every $x_{0} \in [a,b]$ the iteration $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$ converges to the unique fixed-point $\alpha$.

So, in your case: $g(x)=2^{-x}$ is continuous in the interval $[\frac{1}{3},1]$. We know that: $g(\frac{1}{3})=2^{-\frac{1}{3}}<1$ and $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}$. The function $g$ is streactly decreasing, so $g(x)\in [\frac{1}{3},1]$ $\forall x \in [\frac{1}{3},1]$. Furthermore: $|g'(x)|=|-\frac{log(2)}{2^x}|\leq \frac{log(2)}{2^{\frac{1}{3}}}<1$ $\forall x \in [\frac{1}{3},1]$. You can conclude applying the theorem we've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

@Semmah: I made it by desmos.com , an ilustration with $$g(x)=2^{-x}\\\frac13=a\leq x_1\leq1\\
x_2=g(x_1)=g(a)\\
x_3=g(x_2)=g(g(a))\\
x_4=g(x_3)=g(g(g(a)))\\...$$ by scrolling $a$ you can see te fix point of $x=2^{-x}$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/thgnnppzq0
[image]